# Could a Conservative leader who loses the party's confidence vote refuse to resign as Prime Minister?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, prime-minister, conservative-party

At time of writing, a vote of no-confidence in Boris Johnson is due to happen on the evening of 2022-06-06 between 1800 and 2000, as more than 54 letters (15% of all Conservative MPs) have been received by the chair of the 1922 committee. The BBC 'live updates' page notes that: "If Johnson loses, he will be forced to stand down as prime minister and the Conservatives will choose a new leader". What 'forces' him to do so?

A brief summary of [the process of Conservative leadership change procedure is also listed over at the BBC News website](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-45953182). The article includes a helpful image:

[image: helpful image]

The [current rules on Conservative leadership elections](https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN01366/SN01366.pdf) don't actually seem to indicate what happens in the "loses" outcome of the infographic, just that:

> The current rules for electing the leader of the Conservative Party were
> introduced in 1998. A leadership contest can be triggered in two ways:
>
> • If 15% of Conservative MPs write to the Chairman of the 1922
> Committee saying they no longer have confidence in the leader of
> the Conservative Party, or
>
> • if the current leader resigns.

I assume that what happens in such an eventuality is spelt out elsewhere.

There is an 'expectation' that someone who loses the party leadership would resign, as "[the leader of the party that wins the most seats at a general election](https://www.parliament.uk/site-information/glossary/prime-minister/)"; and ["Prime Ministers hold office unless and until
they resign"](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/60641/cabinet-manual.pdf) (PDF, page 21, section 2.8). Further parts of section 2 confirm "it is a matter for the Prime Minister... to judge the
appropriate time at which to resign".

So, losing party leadership isn't like being fired from a job and escorted out by building security! Hypothetically, a Conservative Prime Minister could lose a leadership confidence vote, but refuse to resign as Prime Minister. Is there convention, written guidance, formal procedures, case law, or legislation which would determine or guide what would happen next? I appreciate that there is always the option of Parliament passing a motion, 'this House has no confidence
in Her Majesty’s Government' (section 2.19 in linked PDF) which would mean a general election would take place after 14 days, though this is a catch-all rather than a procedure to handle a hypothetical intransigent PM who refuses to resign.

Comment: As this is my first question on here I explicitly welcome constructive feedback- edits, tag suggestions, links! :) I also note that in the non-hypothetical case it is expected by many political pundits that Boris Johnson will **not** lose the leadership confidence ballot this evening; but I am interested in how a legislature with significant parts running on convention would deal with someone who doesn't play by the usual rules, or do the honourable thing. (or is that 'right honourable thing'..?)

Comment: In theory, the Queen could revoke Johnson's right to serve as PM, though I doubt she'd do this.

Comment: @barrycarter: Unlikely but not entirely impossible. It did [happen in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_Australian_constitutional_crisis), but the governor-general took much of the blame for it, so I doubt her majesty would be pleased to put herself in the same position.

Comment: @barrycarter yes absolutely, I think the cabinet guide PDF linked noted that the last time a PM was dismissed that was in 1834 and "was regarded  as having undermined
the Sovereign"; so I agree that the Queen would be unlikely to do so

Comment: As a further comment: forced resignation is not typical. Resignation is typically something one can always refuse, though often still does too avoid being thrown out.

Comment: @Trilarion In reading parts of the Cabinet Manual I must have overlooked that the PM was elected by Parliament (as opposed to the shared 'fiction' of being appointed by the monarch) ! When and how does this happen? Do they formally pass a motion saying "this House proposes/elects/selects Mrs Haversham as Prime Minister", and can do this at any time? Or is it more typically British nudge-wink 'election', insofar as "Mrs Haversham can 'command the confidence of the House'", therefore the House has (effectively) elected her?

Comment: @bertieb You're right. What I meant is that the Parliament can vote out any PM/government it doesn't like/has no confidence in, therefore any PM must be backed by a majority in Parliament or a no confidence motion would soon follow. It's not the same as electing the PM though.

Comment: @Trilarion ahh, thanks for clarifying :) I figured there's always the 'nuclear option' of no confidence votes triggering a general election, but thought there might just be something less... "hullo IT, have you tried turning parliament off and on again?" ;-P

Comment: Relevant article: "[What happens if Boris Johnson loses tonight’s confidence vote?](https://constitution-unit.com/2022/06/06/what-happens-if-boris-johnson-loses-tonights-confidence-vote/)". The article takes it as axiomatic that if the PM loses this vote, then he will resign, though there is some flexibility on _when_.

Comment: Note that the Fixed-Term Parliaments Act has been repealed, putting the power to call an election back in the hands of the PM. Parliament no longer has any direct power to make that happen.

Comment: Relevant question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39690/is-there-any-mechanism-to-remove-a-uk-prime-minister-on-the-grounds-of-insanity

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Parliament could still, at least in theory, pass new primary legislation to immediately call a new election.

Comment: @cpast: that is true...though this would require control of the Commons timetable, which belongs to the government. But if you have a PM who refuses to go, and a PM-in-waiting who has political power but no governmental power, who is in charge? If the Cabinet tried to exert control, the PM could in theory fire them all. It would all be a bit of a mess. Meanwhile, the last time the opposition gained control of the timetable, it relied on some...controversial interpretations of the rules by Speaker Bercow. There's no guarantee that that would work this time around.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff If the PM is refusing to have Parliament dissolved after an explicit no-confidence motion in the House of Commons, I’d argue you’re well past “a bit of a mess” and into a full-blown constitutional crisis. In that situation, between “the PM successfully defies Parliament” or “Parliament fudges control of the calendar” or “the Queen personally intervenes,” option 2 might be the most palatable.

Comment: Note: I am not a UK citizen. I'm curious why this question is targeted to conservative only? I get that they are the current government, but why would/should this question not be the same, regardless of which 'side' is the government?

Comment: @CGCampbell Party rules (seem to) govern how leadership elections/challenges proceed; since the Conservative party is currently in power any change to their leadership goes by their rules. Your query might be a good place for a n interesting separate question- I'd be interested to know how Labour's (and Lib Dem, SNP) rules vary :)

Comment: An interesting comparison is in 1931 when Labour PM [Ramsay MacDonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsay_MacDonald#Second_Labour_government_(1929%E2%80%931931)) lost the support of many of his own MPs but formed a new government with the support of the Conservatives and Liberals. But I doubt Johnson would get much support from the opposition if he was rejected by his own party.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally the Prime Minister is chosen by the Queen.  By (strong) convention, she chooses a Prime Minister on the advice of her Ministers, ie the Cabinet.

Now the Prime Minister is expected to resign having lost the Leadership and in doing so recommend that the Queen appoint the person who is most likely to command a majority in Parliament - his successor as party leader would be that person.

And that is what would actually happen.

However your question supposes that it doesn't. Ultimately parliament can decide. Because the new party leader can call for a no-confidence vote *in Parliament* which can trigger a general election unless the new leader is permitted to form a government.

One could imagine situations in which the party election was flawed in some way leading to disputes about who actually held a mandate. And in this situation, Parliament could decide to hold a general election, which should clarify the matter.

Such a scenario seems very far fetched - and Johnson isn't Trump - You can keep playing the game of "what if" and it leads ultimately to the Sergeant-at-Arms escorting the rogue Prime Minister to the Tower.  In practice the leader of the Conservative party will know to within a few votes if they have a functioning mandate from the Parliamentary party, and if not they resign from the leadership and the Prime Ministership before Black Rod needs to get nasty.

As an example of when a losing PM didn't *immediately* resign.  Brown, came second in the General election, although the Conservatives held a plurality, not a majority in Parliament.  Brown remained Prime Minister until the Lib Dems entered a coalition with the Conservatives.  Only then, when it was clear that he couldn't command a majority in Parliament, did Brown resign.
Likewise, Johnson would remain as PM until there is a clear successor as leader of the party, and then resign.

Comment: I'm not sure the Brown example is relevant. Gordon Brown remained Prime Minister after a general election under parliamentary rules, the question asks about the consequences of Conservative party rules.

Comment: It's not a perfect analogy, but it does show that a PM remains until a successor is chosen, so there isn't an interregnum with no PM. So in the case of Johnson being no-confidenced as Party leader, he could remain as PM until a successor is chosen.

Comment: I agree with the main points of this answer, but I think some of the details aren't quite right: (a) "Parliament could decide to hold a general election": not any more, it can't; the Fixed-Term Parliaments Act has been repealed, putting the power to call an election back in the hands of the PM. (b) I appreciate that you're being hyperbolic, but note that Black Rod is only in charge of security in the House of Lords.

Comment: (c) It's true that if an MP is being disruptive, the Speaker can order him out; and if the MP refuses, the Serjeant at Arms can forcibly remove him from the Chamber. But that's more-or-less the limits of his power; so no trips to the Tower :-)

Comment: If a vote of confidence were lost, couldn't the Queen ask someone else (e.g. another Conservative MP) to form a new government, probably as a caretaker until the party had elected a new leader?

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer and indulging my what-iffery. As you say in practice it is very unlikely, but we live in ongoing unprecedented times, and what was _inconceivable_ (hopefully that word means what I think it means) five ten or twenty years ago seems to happen now with alarming regularity

Comment: I don't think the Cabinet has a say in who the Queen chooses as Prime Minister. It's unlikely, since the Cabinet is chosen by the PM. What she is obliged to do is choose the Prime Minister who has demonstrated that he or she has the support of the House of Commons - almost always the leader of the largest party in the House.

Comment: @DJClayworth, No the queen takes the advice of her ministers in such matters.  Okay, formally that advice is the advice of the privy council, but the privy council doesn't meet as a body any more, instead it delegates all matters to a committee: the Cabinet, an the Cabinet decides. So, in 2010 it was the Labour Party Cabinet, and in particular Brown, who advised that the Coalition should be invited to form the next government. The Queen does not have any personal role in this

Comment: @JamesK Citation needed.

Comment: Jusr came across the comment drom @JamesK today and it is totally wrong, the Provy Council meets regularly albeit usually with only a handful of members (typically the Leader of the House of Commons, the Leader of the House of the Lords and the Chancellor of the Duchy of Lancaster). It is they who formally convey advice to the Monarch, although the PM can also do so more informally in their regular meetings.

Answer (score 7):

A Prime Minister who refuses to resign at the point where all conventions dictate that he should resign has some overlap with the previously-asked question, "[Is there any mechanism to remove a UK Prime Minister on the grounds of 'insanity'?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39690/is-there-any-mechanism-to-remove-a-uk-prime-minister-on-the-grounds-of-insanity/39695#39695)"

To borrow from part of my answer to that question: if there is general consensus that the PM must resign but is refusing to do so, there is only one option left: dismissal by the Queen.

This last happened in the UK [in 1834](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lamb,_2nd_Viscount_Melbourne) - though the Australian PM was dismissed by the Queen's representative [in 1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_Australian_constitutional_crisis); this was regarded as extremely controversial.

By long-standing convention, the Queen stays out of politics, and only exercises her powers on the advice of ministers; and so any action by an intransigent PM which would risk drawing her into having to use those powers of her own volition would be, at best, very unwelcome.

I would speculate that in this specific scenario, such action might not be as controversial as it could be, especially if it had the backing of the rest of the Cabinet, and if necessary Parliament too. Nonetheless, the conventions exist to try and avoid situations like this. Any PM that were to force the Queen's hand in this way would probably suffer severe reputational damage, if nothing else.

Comment: I wonder, is it a cultural thing about saving face? If someone should resign with 100% probability, one could probably also simply dismiss him/her and achieve the same effect.

Comment: @Trilarion: that's a great question. In this particular case, there's the convention to keep the Queen out of the process as much as possible, and to only act on ministerial advice. So the outgoing PM resigns, and "advises" the Queen who she should appoint as the new PM, which she then does. Separately, there's a convention that ministers are rarely truly fired by the PM; they are instead "asked to resign"; in that case, then it probably is about making an honourable exit. For a PM to actually fire a minister would be a clear sign that they had done something really bad.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff "For a PM to actually fire a minister would be a clear sign that they had done something really bad." - [Michael Gove sacked after he urges PM to resign](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-62073049) Yeah, urging BoJo to do the right thing is clearly "something really bad" :)

Comment: @User65535 ha! I get the impression that it’s personal there. It’s reported that Gove was referred to as a “snake”.

Comment: William Lamb was fired by King William IV in 1834, but reappointed shortly thereafter and served one full term.

Answer (score 2):

The vote of confidence that took place this week was an internal matter to the Conservative Party, conducted privately under party rules - in a committee room of the House.

Strictly speaking it had nothing to do with the constitutional processes for the appointment or removal of a Prime Minister. It is only if a Prime Minister and his government lose a vote of confidence on the floor of the House that he/she is duty-bound to resign. "This House has no confidence in Her Majesty's Government" is the usual wording of the motion.

So, in theory, even if Boris Johnson had lost the party vote of confidence last Monday - he could have continued as Prime Minister - provided that the MPs who expressed no confidence were prepared to support him in a confidence vote in the House. This is not as ridiculous as it might sound because as things currently stand the Government would not win a motion of confidence if all 148 who voted against him in Committee Room 10 on Monday, voted with the opposition in the division lobbies. So his position as Prime Minister currently depends on the support of the Government in the House, of many who voted against the PM under party rules.

However, in practice, had Johnson not even managed a majority last Monday, the party rules would have required his resignation as party leader (not immediately as PM) and a fresh party-leadership election would have taken place. The winner of that election would then, almost certainly have been summoned by the Queen and asked to form a government.

Comment: "the party rules would have required his resignation as party leader" This may just be a linguistic detail but I think that one should never require anyone to resign. Resigning should be something active, out of free will. What the party rules probably mean is that he would be fired from being party leader. Requiring him to resign just sounds better but is slightly harder to understand.

Comment: @Trilarion Everything about our parliamentary system is premised upon people behaving like "gentlemen". And honourable and right-honourable ladies and gentlemen, do not fire, nor get fired, they simply do the right thing when it is expected of them.

Comment: I understand, although many of them aren't really that honorable people and for the layman this all seems to be rather more difficult to understand than necessary, for example this question here. I guess it wouldn't be less honorable if the right thing would be spelled out explicitly in as clear language as possible ("upon losing a no confidence vote the party leader loses also his/her role as leader" might be very clear) because the effect would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Trilarion That may already be the case. Indeed I believe that such a vote of no-confidence automatically triggers a leadership election. The whole process would be controlled by the 1922 Committee.  In Theresa May's case, though she polled 63% in her vote of confidence - Graham Brady, Chair of 1922, later visited her to point out that she really needed to stand down.  Whether Johnson thinks he is more powerful than Brady remains to be seen, but I would doubt that he is.